# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"

Tags: mysql, jdbc

**Question: how to solve this error?**

I am trying to implement a java application which connects the database using JDBC driver.

I try for a week but always return the following error, and I am new to Java and JDBC Driver:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.java.r2pgdm.InputConnection.Connect(InputConnection.java:32)
    at com.java.r2pgdm.InputConnection.<init>(InputConnection.java:26)
    at com.java.r2pgdm.App.main(App.java:23)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.r2pgdm.InputConnection.GetMetaData(InputConnection.java:42)
    at com.java.r2pgdm.InputConnection.<init>(InputConnection.java:27)
    at com.java.r2pgdm.App.main(App.java:23)
```

Thanks for your help!

**System: ubuntu 20.04 ; java 1.8; mysql 8.0.33**

Already did:

1. Install mysql 8.0.33 and start it (see below)

```
COMMAND       PID            USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r     258 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  12197628      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd          317            root    3u  IPv4  12189367      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1838279           mysql   21u  IPv6 205389761      0t0  TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1838279           mysql   23u  IPv6 205389764      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
java      2863309          ubuntu  308u  IPv6  75294475      0t0  TCP 10.15.5.184:7077 (LISTEN)
java      2863309          ubuntu  310u  IPv6  75281272      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

2. And I put the mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar file in the Java application directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      12 Dec  1 09:39 ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu      16 Nov 30 19:35 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    1771 Nov 27 15:36 .classpath
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    2335 Nov 27 15:36 .factorypath
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     541 Nov 27 15:36 .project
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu       6 Nov 27 15:36 .settings/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     179 Dec  1 09:39 config.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    2645 Dec  1 09:39 dependency-reduced-pom.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2481560 Nov 30 20:54 mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    3870 Nov 29 21:17 pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu       4 Nov 27 15:36 src/
drwxrwxr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu      12 Dec  1 10:18 target/
```

3. I also add the dependency in the pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
```

**4. I also have some .sql file before the java_application directory but I don't know what they are used for?**

```
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu     16 Nov 30 19:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 ubuntu ubuntu     35 Dec  1 11:18 ../
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu     13 Nov 27 15:36 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    342 Nov 27 15:36 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu      4 Nov 27 15:36 .vscode/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   1068 Nov 27 15:36 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   1459 Nov 27 15:36 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   1240 Nov 27 15:36 Schema-Oracle.sql
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   1225 Nov 27 15:36 Schema.sql
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   2645 Nov 30 11:05 dependency-reduced-pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu      4 Nov 27 15:36 exports/
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu     12 Dec  1 11:18 java-project/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 348929 Nov 27 15:36 northwind.postgre.sql
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu      5 Dec  1 09:24 sample_java/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    586 Nov 27 15:36 script.cypher
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 198552 Nov 27 15:36 world.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Ensure JDBC Driver is Included
Make sure you have the MySQL JDBC driver in your project's classpath. You can download the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file from the official MySQL website or use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to include it as a dependency.
2.Load/Register the JDBC Driver
Before attempting to connect to the database, explicitly load/register the MySQL JDBC driver using Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"). This step is crucial as it informs Java to load the

If you're using Maven, you can include the MySQL JDBC driver dependency in your pom.xml file:

driver class.

```
// Load the MySQL JDBC driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

// Establish the connection
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "username", "password");
```

Comment: I did use Maven and already include it as a dependency(see the point 3.) But the same error. As for the  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"), I think it is not needed anymore for the driver version higher than 5?